# Issue with "if" statement in combination with input and random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, input

I started today playing a little bit with python, so I'm really new.

I wanted to make a quiz for my little brother, that will generate multiplication functions of random numbers between 0 and 10. Everything went fine, except one thing- when I run the code it always returns false, even when I write a correct input.

I think the main problem is in the "if" statment, and I think the problem is that my input is not really equal to the "multiplication", but I dont know how to fix it.

I can't understand why the "one" is not equal to the "multiplication", I though the "multiplication" is basically the answer to the multiplication of the two random numbers, and if my input is correct it should be equal and print "true".

I would really like to help, I've been breaking my head over it for couple of hours now.
Thanks!

```
import random
import sys
import os

random_num1 = random.randrange(0, 10)
random_num2 = random.randrange(0, 10)

print(random_num1, 'X', random_num2, '=', )

def multiplication(random_num1, random_num2):
    sumNum = random_num1 * random_num2
    return sumNum

one = input()

if(one == multiplication(random_num1, random_num2)):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `one == 'multiplication'`. As is, you're comparing the result of `input` with the function object `multiplication` which will never be `True`.

Comment: But if i put multipication in this " " then it will print true only if i'll write 'multipication' in the input. I'm looking for the input to be equal to the result of the multiplication of the two random numbers

Comment: Close. You are looking for `one == multiplication(random_num1, random_num2)`, as you want to compare the number your brother entered with the *result* of the function call, thus the result of the multiplication.

Comment: By the way: Welcome to the community :). Please make sure to correct the indentation in your code, such that one could copy and execute it.

Comment: It doesnt work like this either :( I already tried... it's really driving me mad lol

Comment: Thank you for the greetings! i would be so happy if you could help me with this!

Comment: Please also add `import random`. I just tried the code. It works for me. Maybe just add `print(multiplication(random_num1, random_num2))` directly before the `input()` to make sure that you enter the correct result. If that doesn't help check the type of one by also adding `print(type(one))`. Normally it should be `int`.

Comment: It didnt help, i checked the type of one and its 'str', what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Then try `int(one) == multi....`. `int` converts the string to an integer.

Comment: OK! this was the problem, I was comparing integers with string, that's why it was not equal. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd still need a 5 year late answer haha. However, here it is:

As I was looking at your code, I decided to remove the multiplication function, and just leave it as a normal action, because it isn't really needed at the moment. I also removed the other two imports, which weren't being used in the code.

Now, the real issue, was that the variable "one" was probably an integer, while the "sumNum" was probably a boolean. So, this is what I did, so it could compare two values of the same type:

```
if int(one) == int(sumNum):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

In the end, it Did work, and here is the full code:

```
import random

random_num1 = random.randrange(0, 10)
random_num2 = random.randrange(0, 10)

print(random_num1, 'X', random_num2, '=', )

sumNum = random_num1 * random_num2

one = input()

if int(one) == int(sumNum):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Sorry if this response is too late, which probably is...